# the link is to download PGSQL is not working anymore

Tags: postgresql

i m trying to use this link to install ht PGsql in my server but the link shows 404 file not found instead can you please help me with another link leading to the same file. NS: the link => https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/9.6/redhat/rhel-6-x86_64/pgdg-centos96-9.6-3.noarch.rpm

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

thank you everyone, i ve found the new link,
https://download.postgresql.org/pub/repos/yum/reporpms/EL-6-x86_64/pgdg-redhat-repo-latest.noarch.rpm
here it is if anyone needs to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Try to download instead PostgreSQL Yum Repository that allows to download with YUM all supported versions including 9.6.

See https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/redhat/

Answer (score 0):

This old minor release is no longer available.

Install 9.6.latest, that is binary compatible and has fewer bugs.